# Google hasn't verified this app. The app is verified

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I verify the app with Google for multiple scopes, login, gmail and calendar. The login and gmail scopes works perfect, but when I want to connect to the calendar I get the following error. Does anyone know if I miss a step in the verification process or if I have to create another api credential for the calendar?

[image: Error screen]

[image: Active scopes]

I already verify the api for login, gmail and calendar.

[Verified image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9dmc.png)

[Full scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Onb.png)

Here is the code for the scope call.

```
public function getConsent()
{
    $client = new Google\Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('App name');
    $client->setScopes(Google\Service\Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setAuthConfig('json-file');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setRedirectUri('https://web.com/calendario/google/callback');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

    return  redirect()->to($authUrl);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where does it show that your app is verified. and what scope are you requesting.

Comment: Hi Linda, thanks for the response.
I edited the original question to add the images. The verified is in the OAuth Consent screen, and the full scopes are in the new image.

Comment: okay what scope are you requesting that is showing the not verified?   can I see the request you are making

Comment: Of course! I edited the original question with the call code

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the following scope in your code

> [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#calendar)
>
> - See, edit, share, and permanently delete all the calendars you can access using Google Calendar

Yet you appear to have verified your app with

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created - Make secondary Google calendars, and see, create, change, and delete events on them

Theses are two different scopes.  If you want to use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar you need to add it to the scope and verify the app again using that scope.  Other wise switch your code to use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created

Note:  I can find no documentation on the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created, yet it does exist in cloud console.  I have contacted the team to see if we can get that scope documented.

Comment: Ohhh ok! Thanks a lot Linda!
I need to use the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created scope, because that's what the web app do. Much appreciate if there is some documentation to access this scope.

Comment: just use it in setscopes the team is going to look at updating the docs

Comment: Thanks Linda! When I added in setscopes it pass the verification, but when I try to create a calendar return a 403 error "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Maybe it would be best that I just add the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar scope to my app.

Comment: Yeah you need full calendar scope to create a new calendar.    This mysterious scope you have verified the team is still trying to figure out where it came from and what access it grants.